# Define custom component from circuit

Tags: circuitikz

I have built a small CMOS Logic Inverter in Circuitikz

```
\begin{tikzpicture}[american voltages, european resistors]
    \draw (-0.5,4)
     node[pmos](notAp){}
     (notAp.D) to [short] ++(0,-1) node[nmos, anchor = D](notAn){}
     (notAp.G) to (notAn.G)
     ($(notAp.G)!0.5!(notAn.G)$) to [short,-o] ++(-1,0) node[anchor=east]{$A$}
     ($(notAp.D)!0.5!(notAn.D)$) to [short,-o] ++(1,0) node[anchor=west]{$O$};
 
\end{tikzpicture}
```

[image]

I now want to use this as a gate in more complex drawings, beein able to connect other CMOS Parts to A, O, G and D without having to copy and paste the whole code, define it as `cmosinverter` and use it like

```
    \begin{tikzpicture}[american voltages, european resistors]
     \draw (-0.5,4)
        node[cmosinverter](notA){}
        (notA.O) to [short] ++(0,-1) node[cmosinverter, anchor = A](notB){};
    \end{tikzpicture}
```

How can I define this as a custom shape and also access the anchors, to use it in a normal circuit drawing like other components?

Comment: i have some tutorials on creating componenets for circuitikz on my web site (http://www.elfsoft2000.com/projects/index.htm). but you probably shouldn't have to go so far.  You can use a scope and treat the `local bounding box` as a node, more of less.  Or use a pic or a savebox.

Comment: As far as I understand i would have to copy and paste the code everytime again just inside of scope tags, when i use it? And can i define custom anchors on those boxes?

So I saw your tutorial under another post, but at first thought its not helping me in my situation. I will try to understand those better, thank you

Comment: If you want multiple copies with anchors, you will need a shape.  which means using basic level pgf commands.  But \pgftext can be used with \includeimage or \usebox.

Comment: As far as i understand i would have to draw every shape myself, if i define it with pgf, but i just want the circuit i have built above copied and connected at other places

Comment: You can create an image using standalone class, or put an entire tikzpicture into a savebox.  The only problem is aligning the anchors with the appropriate points in the image.  (oops, \includegraphics)

Comment: Since you have some responses below that seem to answer your question, please consider marking one of them as ‘Accepted’ by clicking on the tickmark below their vote count (see [How do you accept an answer?](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1852)). This shows which answer helped you most, and it assigns reputation points to the author of the answer (and to you!). It's part of [this site's idea to identify good questions and answers through upvotes and acceptance of answers](//tex.stackexchange.com/about).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(Look down for the best answer, the third is the charm)

#### simple approach: no `anchor`s.

The poor-man way would be to use a `\newcommand`, and start the drawing from the anchor you need. For example, I implemented this that starts from the input:

```latex
\documentclass[border=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage[siunitx, RPvoltages]{circuitikz}
\newcommand{\invcmosA}[1]{%
    {
        coordinate(#1-in) to[short, o-] ++(1,0) coordinate(#1-cross in)
        -- ++(0,1) node[pmos, anchor=G](#1-notAp){}
        (#1-cross in) -- ++(0,-1) node[nmos, anchor=G](#1-notAn){}
        (#1-notAp.D) -- (#1-notAn.D)
        % mark the coordinates
        (#1-notAp.S) coordinate(#1-up)  (#1-notAn.S) coordinate(#1-down)
        coordinate[midway](#1-cross out)
        (#1-cross out) to[short, -o] ++(1,0) coordinate(#1-out)
    }
}

\begin{document}
\begin{circuitikz}
    \draw (0,0) \invcmosA{IA} (4,0) \invcmosA{IB} 
          (IB-up) node[vcc]{} (IB-down) node[vee]{};
    \node [left] at (IA-in) {A};
    \node [right] at (IA-out) {O};
\end{circuitikz}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Now you can do the same starting drawing from the output, or from the up thing, or...

#### let's use a kind-of anchors here

So the approach here is similar. Now I define the subcircuit with an optional argument, and I will use that optional argument to shift the circuit.

In a first run, I will find the distances between every coordinate I want to use as an anchor --- I used `in`, `out`,  `up`, and `down` here and the starting point of my circuit. Then I will add them, sign-flipped, in a relative move command as shown in the `\invcmosAnchor...` commands. (In the code below I have left the code to find the distances in, you normally will remove it)

Now I can use that command to shift the subcircuit with the same effect as an anchor.

```
\documentclass[border=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage[siunitx, RPvoltages]{circuitikz}
\newcommand{\invcmosWithA}[2]{%
    {
        % move everything to the anchor
        #2
        % normal plotting (everything MUST BE relative!)
        coordinate(#1-in)
        to[short, o-] ++(1,0) coordinate(#1-cross in)
        -- ++(0,1) node[pmos, anchor=G](#1-notAp){}
        (#1-cross in) -- ++(0,-1) node[nmos, anchor=G](#1-notAn){}
        (#1-notAp.D) -- (#1-notAn.D)
        % mark the coordinates
        (#1-notAp.S) coordinate(#1-up)  (#1-notAn.S) coordinate(#1-down)
        coordinate[midway](#1-cross out)
        (#1-cross out) to[short, -o] ++(1,0) coordinate(#1-out)
    }
}
\newcommand{\invcmosAnchorIn}{++(0,0)}
\newcommand{\invcmosAnchorOut}{++(-84.78894pt,0)}
\newcommand{\invcmosAnchorUp}{++(-56.3362pt,-50.36137pt)}
\newcommand{\invcmosAnchorDown}{++(56.3362pt,-50.36137pt)}
\begin{document}
\begin{circuitikz}
    % check the distances, then fill the anchor-commands
    \draw (0,5) \invcmosWithA{T}{};
    \draw (4,6) let \p1 = ($(T-out)-(T-in)$) in node[right]{out: \x1,\y1};
    \draw (4,5) let \p1 = ($(T-up)-(T-in)$) in node[right]{up: \x1,\y1};
    \draw (4,4) let \p1 = ($(T-down)-(T-in)$) in node[right]{down: \x1,\y1};

    \draw (0,0) \invcmosWithA{IA}{} -- 
        ++(2,0) \invcmosWithA{IB}{\invcmosAnchorUp}
        (IB-up)  node[vcc]{} (IB-down) node[vee]{};

    \node [above] at (IA-in) {A};
    \node [above] at (IA-out) {OA};
    \node [above] at (IB-in) {B};
    \node [above] at (IB-out) {OB};
\end{circuitikz}
\end{document}
```

[image]

#### Automatically set the "pseudo anchors"

This uses a trick to typeset the first time the subcircuit in a box, and define the anchors there. I have changed the name of the anchors so that they form legal TeX macro names.

You have to call the `\invcmosSetAnchor` macro before using the macros! If you call it after `\begin{document}`, you can peek at it to check what happens...

```latex
\documentclass[]{article}
\usepackage[siunitx, RPvoltages]{circuitikz}
\newbox{\scratchbox}
\newcommand{\invcmosSetAnchors}{
    \sbox{\scratchbox}{%
    \begin{circuitikz}
    \draw (0,0) \invcmosWithA{T}{};
    \foreach [count=\i] \anchor in {in, out, up, down, crossin, crossout, center}
    \draw (0,{2-\i/2}) let \p1 = ($(T-in)-(T-\anchor)$) in
        node[right]{\anchor: \x1,\y1 \expandafter\xdef\csname invcmosAnchor\anchor\endcsname{++(\x1,\y1)}};
    \end{circuitikz}
    }
}

\newcommand{\invcmosWithA}[2]{%
    {
        % move everything to the anchor
        #2
        coordinate(#1-in)
        to[short, o-] ++(1,0) coordinate(#1-crossin)
        -- ++(0,1) node[pmos, anchor=G](#1-notAp){}
        (#1-crossin) -- ++(0,-1) node[nmos, anchor=G](#1-notAn){}
        (#1-notAp.D) -- (#1-notAn.D)
        % mark the coordinates
        (#1-notAp.S) coordinate(#1-up)  (#1-notAn.S) coordinate(#1-down)
        coordinate[midway](#1-crossout)
        ($(#1-crossin)!0.5!(#1-crossout)$) coordinate(#1-center)
        (#1-crossout) to[short, -o] ++(1,0) coordinate(#1-out)
    }
}
\begin{document}

\invcmosSetAnchors
% this works only if you set \invcmosSetAnchors after the \begin{document}
%\usebox{\scratchbox}


\begin{circuitikz}
    \draw (0,0) \invcmosWithA{IA}{} -- 
        ++(2,0) \invcmosWithA{IB}{\invcmosAnchorup}
        (IB-up) node[vcc]{} (IB-down) node[vee]{};
    \node [above] at (IA-in) {A};
    \node [above] at (IA-out) {OA};
    \node [above] at (IB-in) {B};
    \node [above] at (IB-out) {OB};
    \draw [dashed] (IB-out) -- ++(2,0) \invcmosWithA{IC}{\invcmosAnchorcenter};
\end{circuitikz}
\end{document}
```

[image]

The sneak-peek at the '\invcmosSetAnchor` is this:

[image]